# Customizing the counters of theorems, etc

Tags: formatting, theorems, counters

I have a document with *Theorem*s, *Definition*s, *Proposition*s, etc.

In this document, I have a variable; for instance: `\def\idChapter{25}`

I would like all my *Theorem*s, *Definition*s, *Proposition*s to be numbered in the same sequence, with `idChapter` as a chapter.

So, *Definition 25.1* then *Proposition 25.2* and *Theorem 25.3*, etc.

Can you help me?

Here is a MWE. Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{defi}[theo]{Definition}
\newtheorem{prop}[theo]{Proposition}

\begin{document}

\begin{theo}
Test
\end{theo}

\begin{defi}
Test
\end{defi}

\begin{prop}
Test
\end{prop}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you writing chapters in article? And not in book where you could just have used  `\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[chapter]` and you're done.

Comment: You can just use `\renewcommand\thetheo{\idChapter.\arabic{theo}}`

Comment: Not sure what you want `idChapter` to use for, but probably `\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{idChapter}

\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{defi}[theo]{Definition}
\newtheorem{prop}[theo]{Proposition}

\renewcommand\thetheo{\arabic{idChapter}.\arabic{theo}}

\setcounter{idChapter}{25}
\begin{document}

\begin{theo}
Test
\end{theo}

\begin{defi}
Test
\end{defi}

\begin{prop}
Test
\end{prop}

\end{document}` could help.

Comment: Thanks @daleif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use

```
\renewcommand\thetheo{\idChapter.\arabic{theo}}
```

Though I'd probably not write chapters for something in `article`, with `book` you can just use

```
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[chapter]
```